# Dropbox Synchronization: how to manage AndroidManifest entry

Tags: android, android-manifest, dropbox

I'm developing an Android Application using Eclipse. I want synchronize application database on dropbox so I'm using dropbox sdk. I created my app on dropbox to have the app key pair and I wrote this key in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<data android:scheme="db-xxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

I developed the upload functionality using key pair and it work perfectly.

So... I developed an activity where application user can specify own key pair. This pair is stored in a SharedPreferences structure.

My question is:  this functionality edit data in SharedPreferences structure but not in AndroidManifest.xml file, so the synchronization don't work. How to manage this aspect?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to modify the key in the manifest because it uniquely identifies your application in the user's Dropbox. What do you want to do with this operation?

The operation of syncronize the database is complex. I'm also trying to make this function with DropBox. Follow these post if you are interested like me: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=97600#post-532177
[Android database synchronize with Dropbox SyncAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203832/android-database-synchronize-with-dropbox-syncapi)