# Android database synchronize with Dropbox SyncAPI

Tags: android, dropbox

I would like to synchronize the database of an Android app with the new Dropbox SyncAPI.
I don't understand very well the tutorial on https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/tutorial/android,
and the example of the "Notes" is a little confusing for me. I can still log in to the platform with the API, and I know that I should use the database as a single file to be treated, obtaining its path.
My questions are: what are the main key points to do this (handler? listener to file?)? 
Where can I find other examples to study for my case?
Thanks.

Comment: If I put the database file in a folder and I sync it with Sync API, could be a solution?
When new updates happens, I would wait for the file to be downloaded and next I import the DB into the app with the appropriate android function.
What do you think? is a too complicated solution or there are more simple?